# API is the best choice for doing task X? Or My Own Method?

Tags: c#, java, performance, groovy, processing-efficiency

In java, Groovy, C# there are several API's available. For example lets say there is an API X which does the job of sorting. And even I have the method of my own which does the job of API x.

Which one to choose, API or my own method? What I means is, all API functions as fast as it should? Or there are cases where my method run fast than available API's?

Comment: The only way to find out if a given API is fast enough, is to measure.

Comment: Even if you could write an API faster, often its not needed. You are just as likely to introduce bug which might not be in the more roundly tested API.

Answer (score 1):

The question is way too generic but usually you don't want to re-invent the weel. Common APIs and libraries are maintained and developed by a lot of people, are tested and optimized. Usually you will end up doing a worse job on your own.

You should invest your time implementing the things that are specific to your goal.

If you really want to be able to check what the libraries and APIs are doing there are several open source implementation that you can review and maybe also improve.

This of course depends on what do you need (which API, which task, which problem).

Answer (score 1):

The unhelpful vague answer is: whichever does the job best given your requirements. The easy answer is: usually the provided API.